# Understanding Gerrit’s Push Merge Commit permission

Tags: git, gerrit

I don’t quite understand Gerrit's access control of Push Merge Commit, described here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#category_push_merge

I set the Push Merge Commit permission to be blocked or denied on refs/for/*, but I still can push and merge using the following command, which skips the review process.

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%submit
```

What is the Push Merge Commit permission used for?

Answer (score 2):

The "Push Merge Commit" access right, permits the user to push a "merge commit" to review in Gerrit.

A "Merge commit" is a commit with 2 parents, as the commit "M" in the following example:

```
A --- B --- C --- M  <= master
                /
               /
        D --- E      <= feature
```

Sometimes, in some special situations or projects, repository administrators prefer to restrict, for some developers, the push permission of these commits to the repository.

The "git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%submit" command, you have mentioned, pushes the commit directly to the branch, bypassing the review process. This is not related to "merge commits".

To prevent the auto-merge during push you need to restrict the "Submit" permission on "refs/for/".

See more details in Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#auto_merge).

Comment: I see, thank you. Just realized that Push merge commit is an operation of git...  Then, is any gerrit permission to block the push to refs/for/master%submit which skips code review?

Comment: Yes, but restrict submit permission of refs/for also restrict the user's submit from the gerrit web(after reviewed +2)

Comment: No. The auto-merge during push is controlled by the "Submit" permission on "refs/for/<ref>" reference and the regular submit is controlled by the same, but on "refs/heads/<ref>" one.